# I can't connect to my local SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

I'm currently learning ADO.NET on C#. I'm learning by a book and tutorials that I found online. I wanted to try some of the samples to get myself familiarized with the whole SQL connnection and command objects and so on. Hence, I tried this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class SqlDemo
    {
        public void InitConnection ()
        {
            string connString = @"data source=C:\SQL Server 2000 Sample Databases; database=northwnd; integrated security=SSPI";
            SqlConnection conn = null;

            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection (connString);
                conn.Open ();
                Console.WriteLine ("DataBase connection established");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("DataBase connection not established");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null) conn.Close ();
            }

            Console.ReadKey (true);
        }

        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            SqlDemo d = new SqlDemo ();
            d.InitConnection ();
        }
    }
}
```

And no matter how I try, I can connect to the local database. `"data source=(local)"` don't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things:

1) It looks like you may have a typo in your database name. It should probably be:

```
database=northwind
```

2) Your data source should be `(local)` or `.` OR you may have an instance installed, in which case you may need to include the instance name as well, such as `.\SQLExpress` or `.\SQLServer`.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. I created a form application and added a datagrid and then I used it to connect to the lcoal data base file I have in my computer. This is the value of the connectionString Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\SQL Server 2000 Sample Databases\NORTHWND.MDF";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to connect to a database file using a path:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf; Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

From: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

However, you may also need to "Attach" the database to Sql Server.  In Management studio, right click the Databases folder and select "Attach..."

Comment: Yeah. Thank you Steve. That seems to work a better. Quick question. What is the difference between "data source=(local)" and "data source=.\SQLExpress". The first one doesn't seem to work for me, even though that's how the have it in the books and online tutorials.

Comment: I googled "data source=(local)" and the first hit answered your question.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/ca864a05-eac9-45b1-bd29-a8e1ba4c41c5/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2000, then just put 'local' or simply '.' (exclude the quotes) for the data source. And you have a typo in the database name. It should be 'Northwind'